# GET Parameters not passing with window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, redirect, getparameter

Ok, so i am changing url when the bootstrap3 modal `hidden.bs.modal` event is triggered, here's an example of that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#exampleModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        window.location = "http://example.com/example.php?test=1";
    });
});
```

The problem is that when `window.location` is set the `test` parameter isn't passed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it successfully going to `http://example.com`?

Comment: What do you mean with "not passed"? Is the modal URL http://example.com/example.php?test=1 or http://example.com/example.php?

Or when you try to access "test" you see nothing? If so, how are you fetching "test"?

Comment: @Omnisite I mean that when the page refreshes ?test=1 is not appened to the URL. And i am accessing the variable via $_GET in php